# Ember.js: Using data from Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ember.js

I am building my very first WebApp using Ember.js. Could someone point me in the right direction as to how I can GET user-JSON data to use in a model via the Facebook Graph API? The documentation is a bit scarce in that regard and googling around, I have found many different approaches.

The login is up and running, so I've got the access key ready to go.

Answer (score -1):

You can GET to graph.facebook.com/me for the current user's data.

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your post to provide example code for how to do this.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. That I can GET via the API  URL is no mystery, I'd say.